# Fatal error: Class 'AppModel' not found in .../lib/Cake/Utility/ClassRegistry.php on line 186

Tags: cakephp, console

I'm trying to define a shell for my Cakephp App. This is the code:

```
<?php

App::uses('AppModel','Model');

class UserShell extends AppShell {

    public $uses = array('User');

    public function show() {
        $user = $this->User->findByUsername($this->args[0]);
        $this->out(print_r($user, true));
        }
}

?>
```

but when I try to execute the command

```
./cake user show anyUserName
```

the console returns the error

```
Class 'AppModel' not found in /var/www/cakeprova_2.5.7/lib/Cake/Utility/ClassRegistry.php on line 186
```

I have the file AppModel.php at its own place, so I don't know what's wrong... Can anybody help me please?

Answer (score 1):

You are using App::uses() wrong.
It is meant to include classes you need in **this file** not others.
So

a) Fix your statements in this shell file, and add `App::uses('AppShell', 'Console/Command');`

b) You are most likely missing an `App::uses('AppModel','Model');` in your User model class file then.
  Because there you are saying `class User extends AppModel {}`, right?

Comment: Thank you Mark! The error was explained: I put the file in the wrong directory:

    /lib/Cake/Console/Command

but after putting it in the right dir:

    /app/Console/Command

it worked. But great thank for your help

Comment: Nonetheless my statements are still valid. Be verbose and correct about the App::uses() statements.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you Mark! The error was explained: I put the file in the wrong directory:

```
/lib/Cake/Console/Command
```

but after putting it in the right dir:

```
/app/Console/Command
```

it worked. But great thank for your help

Answer (score 0):

I found this error when I migrate cakephp 1.3 to 2.10

I update Model/AppModel.php as below and fixed the error.

```
App::import('Vendor', 'Find.find_app_model');
class AppModel extends FindAppModel {
```

To

```
App::uses('Model', 'Model');
class AppModel extends Model {
```